# will "tempfile.mkdtemp" generate two same files?

Tags: python

I saw following code:

```
logdir = pathlib.Path(tempfile.mkdtemp())/"tensorboard_logs"
shutil.rmtree(logdir, ignore_errors=True)
```

I know the second command is to delete files in order to prevent the existing file affect future "write" "copy" or other command.But I don't understand why delete the file just being built? It should be empty. How possible the command "tempfile.mkdtemp()" generate two same name files?

Comment: Where did you see this? More context would be helpful. Otherwise you are right, it does not make any sense other than being a "just in case" statement.

Comment: The Linux man page for `mkdtemp` says it won't generate a name that's a duplicateof an existing file at the time of a call which is _not_ the same as saying it won't ever generate a same name it has before — so the code doesn't make sense. How is this directory going to be used anyway if it's deleted?